# Python 3.6 multiprocessing on windows 10 using pool.apply_async to create new threads stops working after many iterations

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have recently started working with pythons multiprocessing library, and decided that using the Pool() and apply_async() approach is the most suitable for my problem. The code is quite long, but for this question I've compressed everything that isn't related to the multiprocessing in functions.

### Background information

Basically, my program is supposed to take some data structure and send it to another program that will process it and write the results to a txt file. I have several thousands of these structures (N*M), and there are big chunks (M) that are independent and can be processed in any order. I created a worker pool to process these M structures before retrieving the next chunk. In order to process one structure, a new thread has to be created for the external program to run. The time spend outside the external program during the processing is less than 20 %, so if I check Task Manager, I can see the external program running under processes.

### Actual problem

This works very well for a while, but after many processed structures (any number between 5000 and 20000) suddenly the external program stop showing up in the Task Manager and the python children runs at their individual peak performance (~13% cpu) without producing any more results. I don't understand what the problem might be. There are plenty of RAM left, and each child only use around 90 Mb. Also it is really weird that it works for quite some time and then stops. If I use ctrl-c, it stops after a few minutes, so it is semi-irresponsive to user input.

One thought I had was that when the timed-out external program thread is killed (which happens every now and then), maybe something isn't closed properly so that the child process is waiting for something it cannot find anymore? And if so, is there any better way of handling timed-out external processes?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError

N = 500         # Number of chunks of data that can be multiprocessed
M = 80          # Independed chunk of data
timeout = 100   # Higher than any of the value for dataStructures.timeout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = [None]*M
    savedData = []

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for iteration in range(N):
            dataStructures = [generate_data_structure(i) for i in range(M)]

            #---Process data structures---
            for iS, dataStructure in enumerate(dataStructures):
                results[iS] = pool.apply_async(processing_func,(dataStructure,))

            #---Extract processed data---
            for iR, result in enumerate(results):
                try:
                    processedData = result.get(timeout=timeout)
                except TimeoutError:
                    print("Got TimeoutError.")

                if processedData.someBool:
                    savedData.append(processedData)
```

Here is also the functions that create the new thread for the external program.

```
import subprocess as sp
import win32api as wa
import threading

def processing_func(dataStructure):
    # Call another program that processes the data, and wait until it is finished/timed out
    timedOut = RunCmd(dataStructure.command).start_process(dataStructure.timeout)

    # Read the data from the other program, stored in a text file
    if not timedOut:
        processedData = extract_data_from_finished_thread()
    else:
        processedData = 0.
    return processedData


class RunCmd(threading.Thread):
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000

    def __init__(self, cmd):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.p = None

    def run(self):
        self.p = sp.Popen(self.cmd, creationflags=self.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
        self.p.wait()

    def start_process(self, timeout):
        self.start()
        self.join(timeout)
        timedOut = self.is_alive()

        # Kills the thread if timeout limit is reached
        if timedOut:
            wa.TerminateProcess(self.p._handle,-1)
            self.join()
        return timedOut
```